# How do I define an entry point for a project that has nothing but nUnit tests?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nunit

How do I define an entry point for a project that has nothing but nUnit tests?

I have a bunch of nUnit TestFixture() classes that instantiate classes that return SQL data. The TestFixture classes have TestFixtureSetUp that contain all the parameters they need to instantiate the classes they’re using for tests.

I can run Unit Test Sessions in ReSharper, but I need to run the project in Debug and the entry point I have is a Windows Form. So how do I kick off and debug the tests? I thought nUnit had a test list that would fire the tests in order... Do I need an nUnit test constructor? so this is either an entry point question or an nUnit test list question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I define an entry point for a project that has nothing but nUnit tests?

You don't.  A test project is typically compiled as a library (DLL), not an executable, which means it doesn't require an entry point.

Instead of executing the project as an exe, you should just debug the tests.  This is often done, when using nUnit, by [attaching the debugger to the nUnit process](http://codebetter.com/paullaudeman/2004/03/18/nunit-tip-debugging-your-unit-tests/) then running the tests.  However, tools like [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) will simplify this further by allowing you to directly debug from within Visual Studio.  Given that you're using ReSharper, you should be able to choose to [debug from within Resharper as well](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html).

Comment: After rekajiggering my project I attached the debugger to the nUnit process and it works great. I removed the executable project from the solution to keep it clean and all is well. I'll use the the ReSharper route if work buys the license after the trial period.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Resharper now, I didn't realize I could right-click and debug...  However, now my Log4Net logging isn't logging so I'm researching that issue.  But if you have an easy answer I'd love to hear it  :)